# How to install newest version of gems not mentioned in Gemfile.lock with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler, bundle-install

When I add a gem to a project's `Gemfile` for the first time, but I have installed the gem previously while working on another project, it uses the existing version of the gem, rather than the latest version of the gem available.

For example, using bundler version 1.11.2, I added `gem 'rubocop'` to a project's `Gemfile`, and running `bundle install` resulted in it using RuboCop version 0.42.0, rather than the current (as of 21 October 2016) version of 0.44.1:

```
rubocop (0.42.0)
  parser (>= 2.3.1.1, < 3.0)
  powerpack (~> 0.1)
  rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
  ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
  unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
```

Running `bundle update rubocop` resulted in version 0.44.1 being used, without any pre-existing gems having their version changed. This indicates there weren't any constraints shopping me from using RuboCop version 0.44.1.

```
rubocop (0.44.1)
  parser (>= 2.3.1.1, < 3.0)
  powerpack (~> 0.1)
  rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
  ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
  unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
```

When running `bundle install`, how can I tell it, for gems that aren't mentioned in `Gemfile.lock`, to download the newest compatible version of the gem, rather than use an older version which happens to be available on the local machine?

I tried looking at http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-install.1.html but nothing there seemed to be relevant.

Comment: What do you mean "aren't mentioned in lockfile"? If it's not in lockfile, then it's not a gem in gemfile or one of their dependencies and, therefore, bundle has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev When I've just added a gem to `Gemfile`, and haven't yet run `bundle install`, which would list the gem in `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: You sure that bundler doesn't install the latest version? I think it does.

Comment: `bundle update`

Comment: @Aetherus that updates everything.

Comment: Then `bundle update some_gem`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've added an example of this happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have newest version gem, remove version in `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`  again.

Comment: I've added an example reproduction to my question, suggesting that this approach won't work, at least for the version of bundler I was using.